# Symfony 3.4 conflict between form field name and entity with option indexBy

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to make a form but it seems there is a conflict caused by the OneToMany annotation's option indexBy="label"

> The name "Exemple frais" contains illegal characters. Names should start with a letter, digit or underscore and only contain letters, digits, numbers, underscores ("_"), hyphens ("-") and colons (":").

Where "Exemple frais" is my entity's label.

```
/**
 * User.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

    (...)

    /**
     * @var Frais[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Frais", mappedBy="user",indexBy="label")
     */
    private $frais;
```

Here, my form field:

```
->add(
            'frais',
            CollectionType::class,
            [
                'entry_type'   => FraisType::class,
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'prototype'    => true
            ]
        )
```

Even if i set the next functions in FraisType:

```
 public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'frais';
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'frais';
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(
        [
            'data_class' => Frais::class
        ]
    );
}
```

The only solution I found is to change my CollectionType to an EntityType. Did you know any solution to avoid me from changing that ?

Comment: Are you sure you are providing the right code? There is not a single occurence of "Exemple" in it

Comment: That's the problem. "Exemple" is the label attribute's value of one Frais

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. I choose to use the "data" form field option. **It is not really an answer to my question but it works**

```
            ->add(
                'frais',
                CollectionType::class,
                [
                    'entry_type'   => FraisType::class,
                    'allow_add'    => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'prototype'    => true,
                    'data' => $this->em->getRepository(FraisDivers::class)->findBy(['user' => $this->user])
                ]
            )
```

This way prevent to get the Frais entities by the relational link and prevent indexOf option to mess up.